# How to pass props from URL in VueJS when redirect in vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-router

I have functions which is redirecting user in 4 seconds, but I need to pass props somehow:

```
    setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(intervalId)
      this.$router.push({ path: `/${this.$store.state.locale}/my-cart` })
    }, 4000)
```

I was trying to do something like that:

`this.$router.push({ name: '/${this.$store.state.locale}/my-cart', params: {step: '2'} })`

This didn't work, this route redirects on main page, so, how can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried to add the option `props: true` to the route configuration? Check this: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode

Comment: Actually, I was wrong and the question is wrong. Props is about components, but there I have static url `/my-cart`. So, this won't work this way, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/${this.$store.state.locale}/my-cart', params: {step: '2' }})
```

please change the `name` and replace `path` into code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use url to declare for a path. You need to change "name" to "path".

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/${this.$store.state.locale}/my-cart', params: {step: '2'} })
```

Else you want to use name, you can pass value of name attribute that define in route.js file instead pass url.

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'namePath', params: {step: '2'} })
```